# Does ssh really fail correctly escaping remote commands?

Tags: ssh, escape-characters

I take this simple example in bash:

```
echo a "b  c"  d
```

The correct output is:

```
a b  c d
```

Which is internally 'encoded' as an array of three arguments while the middle one (containing `b` and `c`) is 4 characters long and contains 2 spaces. This is the debug output when `set -x` is enabled in bash (not dash)

```
echo a "b  c"  d
+ echo a 'b  c' d
a b  c d
```

Now, the ssh command seems to completely ignore this and seems to concatenate this internally to one single string which is not correct, otherwise I cannot explain the results:

```
$ ssh user@remotehost -- echo a "b  c"  d
+ ssh user@remotehost -- echo a 'b  c' d
a b c d
$ ssh user@remotehost echo a "b  c"  d
+ ssh user@remotehost echo a 'b  c' d
a b c d
$ ssh user@remotehost 'echo a "b  c"  d'
+ ssh user@remotehost 'echo a "b  c"  d'
a b  c d
```

As you can see, the last line works best, but there I have a problem if the string gets more complicated, for example this:

```
$ text="doesn't work"
+ text='doesn'\''t work'

$ echo "$text"
+ echo 'doesn'\''t work'
doesn't work

$ ssh user@remotehost echo "$text"
+ ssh user@remotehost echo 'doesn'\''t work'
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

$ ssh user@remotehost "echo $text"
+ ssh user@remotehost 'echo doesn'\''t work'
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

$ ssh user@remotehost "echo \'$text\'"
+ ssh user@remotehost 'echo \'\''doesn'\''t work\'\'''
'doesnt work\

$ ssh user@remotehost "echo '$text'"
+ ssh user@remotehost 'echo '\''doesn'\''t work'\'''
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

The question is: I there *any* way to execute a remote command and passing variables in the best practice way (`"$variable"`, multiple arguments), **so that I don't have to care about its contents**, or if its contents is dangerous?

The same limitation also seems to apply to `sh -c` which is probably the source of the problem, other commands do better (they directly call the binary instead of using a shell):

```
$ sudo -- echo a 'b  c' d
[sudo] password for user: 
a b  c d

$ nohup echo a 'b  c' d
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
$ cat nohup.out
a b  c d
```

Comment: Hint: where does the quoted sequence `"a  a"` in your command get expanded, on the local machine or on the remote one?

Comment: How can I test it? Or differently said: what do you mean with expanded? One piece of code seems trying to convert an array of string to a single string with quotations but makes mistakes (incorrect escaping)

Comment: SSH runs commands by doing the equivalent of `$SHELL -c '...'` on the remote system (as you guessed), so you have two levels of quoting: the one on the local shell you're using to run ssh, and the one on the remote shell SSH uses to run the commands. Getting arbitrary variables across is a tricky business; I try to copy scripts to the remote server whenever possible so that the only level of quoting involved is within the script.